# render array of object into a <li> in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read an article and the author critic below code, I wonder what's wrong with it. I was starting to learn React, too bad the author did not point out what's his problem with the code below. I tested the code below, it's running fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const TodoItems = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      items : [
        {id:1,name:"Gym"},
        {id:2,name:"Jump"},
        {id:3,name:"Racing"}
      ] 
    }
  },
  renderItem(){
    return(
      <ul>
      {this.state.items.map((item,i) => 
        <li key={i}>item.name</li>
      )}
      </ul>
    ) 
  },
  render(){
    return (
      <renderItem />
    )
  }

})

ReactDOM.render(<TodoItems />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The method renderItem should be outside as a functional or stateless component:

```
const RenderItem = (props) => {
    return(
      <ul>
      {props.items.map((item,i) => 
        <li key={i}>item.name</li>
      )}
      </ul>
    ) 
  };
```

The render method of the parent component should be:

```
render(){
    return (
      <RenderItem items={this.state.items} />
    )
  }
```

This is the standard way that we write React components. It causes maintainability issues when you write it that way.

Answer (score 0):

**In short, you code will not ensure component re-usability**.

With React, you'll get the most of **re-usability**. In the above code, I can see that you are trying to render the items in the state in the function `renderItem()`. The need of using `functions` in any language is also to ensure **re-usability**. So, in React when you when you want to re-use a part which will return a HTML elements, make it as a separate component.

See the following fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/b6v6fxrj/1/

Here, I made the `renderItem()` as a separate component `<RenderItem>` which can be reused in `n` number of other components..

Comment: Why would u use a `li`?

Comment: @ThianKianPhin Meaning?